# A question about application of Levy's $0-1$ law

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

The question and a hint are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166557/application-of-l%C3%A9vy-zero-one-law). I have a couple of questions about the question and the hint. OP says if $A_m$ is the event that $X_n\leq m$ eventually, then $\cup_m A_m = \{\text{limsup } X_n < \infty\}$. But shouldn't the event $\{\text{limsup } X_n < \infty\}$ mean $X_n\geq m$ eventually for some $m$?

As for the hint, just wanted to confirm that if $B_n$ is the event that $X_n\leq m$ i.o., then $\cup_n B_n = \{\text{liminf } X_n<\infty\}$? Thus $D\supset \{\text{liminf } X_n<\infty \}$ and $1=P(D\cup \{\text{liminf }X_n=\infty\})\leq P(D\cup \{\text{lim }X_n=\infty\}) = 1$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a non-random sequence $(a_n)$ has a finite $\limsup$, it means that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{k\geq n}a_k$ is finite (say equal to $M$) hence there exists some $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $\sup_{k\geq n}a_k\leq M+1$ and all the terms are eventually smaller than $m:=M+1$.

Comment: Thank you! Following this logic for the question, On the event $\{\text{liminf }X_n<\infty\}$, $X_n\leq M+1$ i.o. Thus $P(D|X_1,..X_n)\geq \delta(M+1)>0$ i.o. and $P(D|X_1,..X_n)\rightarrow 1_D$. May I please know why that implies $D\supset \{\text{liminf }X_n<\infty\}$?